# Why does display: flex work on <body> but not <html> tag?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Title says it all. For some reason, my elements position and resize properly when `display: flex` is applied to the `body` tag but with the `<html>` tag, nothing changes. Why is that?

Comment: [It's generally considered a good practice to put styles in the `<body>` element.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/41132)

Comment: You shouldn't use 'flexbox layout' like that, but it works: assign `display: block` (or even `display: flex`) to anything inside `<html>`, like `<head> <link> <meta> <script>` etc. and set `html { display: flex; flex-direction: column }` and your entire document will be shown. I use this to toggle the display of CSS and JS on/off for debugging. You can even make a `<style>` block `contenteditable="true"` for runtime editing.... So, show your code and we'll have a look why it is not working....[reprex]

Comment: I wanted to use the `flexbox layout` for my entire page. It doesn't work on the html tag because from @Quentin flexbox doesn't affect the 'grandchildren elements' which is now why I have it set on the body tag

Comment: Yep, I got that the second time around. I learn from SO too: to do better reading....;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the elements you want to position are not children of the `html` element, only `head` and `body` are.

Comment: It affects the position of children, but not grandchildren or deeper descendents. There is no such thing an indirect child in HTML.

Comment: @RenevanderLende — I specifically said "the elements you want to position". Sure, you could make `head` visible and then use flexbox to lay it and the `body` out, but that is very clearly not what the OP was trying to do (because when they applied `display: flex` to the `body` it "worked", so the elements the OP wants to layout must be the children of the body.

Comment: @RenevanderLende — As I said, they said they wanted to affect the elements that were affected when they applied `display: flex` to the body.